# Generating C++ com interface for microsoft word using midl compiler

Tags: c++, ms-word, midl, oleview

I'm trying to create the microsoft word COM C++ interface definition using the midl compiler. I used oleview.exe to save the "Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library" (MSWORD.OLB) to a file called MSWORD.idl.

When compiling this idl file I get errors. For instance:

> .\msword.idl(3932) : error MIDL2025 : syntax error : expecting a type
>   specification near "single"

I have fixed this by:

```
typedef float single;
```

Then the next error is displayed:

> .\msword.idl(4004) : error MIDL2025 : syntax error : expecting a type
>   specification near "WdDocumentMedium"

The lines around 4004:

```
[id(0x0000019e), helpcontext(0x0970019e)]
HRESULT SetDefaultTheme(
                        [in] BSTR Name, 
                        [in] WdDocumentMedium DocumentType);
```

`WdDocumentMedium` is defined as an enum but after this line.

Another undefined enum is `MsoLanguageID`.

Using the visual basic editor inside word, I have checked the necessary libraries using the object browser.

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: How do I get it to compile without errors?